# VBA Record when a new row is populated

Tags: excel, vba, row

I was wondering if there is a better method to record when a new row is populated in VBA. I have a large dataset and want to record when a new row is input, I have written the following code to essentially record when information in columns C,D and E is populated which denotes a new row is added on a separate worksheet that outputs the date the row was added, the sheet it was added in and then its row identifier.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const cCols As String = "C:E"
    
    Const dName As String = "Log"
    Const dCol As String = "A"
    Const dcCol As String = "C"
    
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = Columns(cCols).Resize(Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)


    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, crg)
    Dim sName As String: sName = ActiveSheet.Name
     
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Dim ddcrg As Range: Set ddcrg = dws.Columns(dcCol)
    
    Dim arg As Range
    Dim rrg As Range
    Dim srAddress As String
    Dim ddFound As Range
    
  
 
    
    For Each arg In srg.Areas
        For Each rrg In arg.Rows
            srAddress = sName & "!" & rrg.Address(0, 0)
            Set ddFound = ddcrg.Find(srAddress, , xlFormulas, xlWhole)
            If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = 0 Then
            
             If ddFound Is Nothing Then
                
                With Sheets("Log")
                    Set dfCell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, dCol) _
                        .End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                        dfCell.Value = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
                        dfCell.Offset(, 1).Value = ActiveSheet.Name
                        dfCell.Offset(, 2).Value = srAddress
                End With
            End If
         End If
       Next
    Next
```

This is long and super slow especially when the data set is longer just recording the row takes a few seconds. Would anyone be able to suggest a faster way, or point me towards a method or learning resources for something like this?

Comment: Maybe ask at [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What happens if your dataset gets sorted at some point?  Or you delete a row in the middle?  FYI  `Match()` would be much faster than `Find()`